# Laravel 9 Vue js 3 Pagination

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, pagination

I'm displaying data from database by looping it, and I want it to be only 3 data per page, and when the user click on the pagination button, it will display another 3 data, so this is my controller

```
public function index()
{

    $list_lowongan = Lowongan::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();

    return response()->json($list_lowongan);
}
```

template

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />
  <div class="pageLowongan" id="posisiTersedia">
      <h1><span class="judulLowongankarir">Posisi yang tersedia</span></h1>
      <p class="bawahJudulLowongankarir">JAI’ membuka lowongan pekerjaan yang<br class="brlowyang"> sesuai dengan dirimu, mari tumbuh bersama<br class="brlowyang"> dan upgrade skillmu!</p>
      <div class="courses-container" v-for="(value, index) in paginatedList" :key="value.id" id="slotKerjaP">
        <div class="course">
          <div class="course-info1" id="slotKerja1">
            <h2 class="lowongank1"> {{ value.title }}</h2>
            <button id="pagiLowongan2" v-on:click="toggleBody(index)"><img src="images/vectorlow.png" :class="{ 'rotated': value.isRotated}" id="vectorapply"></button>
              <p class="descJobk1">{{ value.body }}</p>
              <p class="textDesc" v-if="value.showBody">Job Description : </p>
              <div v-html="value.jobdesc" class="textDescKecil" v-if="value.showBody"></div>
              <p class="textDesc" v-if="value.showBody">Requirements : </p>
              <div v-html="value.req" class="textDescKecil" v-if="value.showBody"></div>
              <p class="textDesc" v-if="value.showBody">Work Type : {{ value.worktype }} </p>
              <p class="Locationlow" v-if="value.showBody">Location : {{ value.location }} </p>
              <p class="Locationlow" v-if="value.showBody">Employment Type : {{ value.employmenttype }} </p>
              <router-link :to="`applys/${value.id}`" class="routesApply" v-if="value.showBody">Apply</router-link>          
              <hr class="garisJobk1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>         
        <nav aria-label="naviMedia1">
          <ul class="pagination" id="pagiIpad10">
            <li class="page-item5"><a class="page-link"  type="button" data-bs-slide="prev" id="pagiKarir1" v-on:click="prevPage"><img src="images/mediaarrow2.png"></a></li>
            <li class="page-item6"><a class="page-link"  type="button" data-bs-slide="next" id="pagiKarir2" v-on:click="nextPage"><img src="images/mediaarrow1.png"></a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

</template>
```

scripts

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      'form': {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        jobdesc: '',
        req: '',
        worktype: '',
        location: '',
        employmenttype: '',
      },
      list_lowongan: [],
      currentPage: 1,
      itemsPerPage: 3,
      isRotated: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    paginatedList() {
      const start = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.itemsPerPage;
      const end = start + this.itemsPerPage;
      return this.list_lowongan.slice(start, end);
    },
    totalPages() {
      return Math.ceil(this.list_lowongan.length / this.itemsPerPage);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('on mounted');
    axios.get('lowongan/list').then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      this.list_lowongan = response.data
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  },
  methods: {
    toggleBody(index) {
      this.list_lowongan[index].showBody = !this.list_lowongan[index].showBody;
      this.list_lowongan[index].isRotated = !this.list_lowongan[index].isRotated;
    },
    prevPage() {
      if (this.currentPage > 1) {
        this.currentPage--;
      }
    },
    nextPage() {
      if (this.currentPage < this.totalPages) {
        this.currentPage++;
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    currentPage: function (newPage, oldPage) {
      console.log(`Current page changed from ${oldPage} to ${newPage}`);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have successfully made it only displaying 3 data per page, but when I click on the pagination, nothing happens, I already add a console log to see if its working, but still nothing happens when I click on the button, What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to handle all the pagination logic from the client side but you get only 3 items from your controller with the `take(3)` so it couldn't works.

You should send the `currentPage` and the `itemsPerPage` to your controller, and refresh the data when `prevPage()` and `nextPage()` are called.

You could do something like this (not tested it, just to give an idea) :

Controller :

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
    $currentPage = $request->input('currentPage');
    $itemsPerPage = $request->input('itemsPerPage');
    $list_lowongan = Lowongan::orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->skip(($currentPage >= 1 ? $currentPage -1 : 0) * $itemsPerPage)
        ->take($itemsPerPage)
        ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'items' => $list_lowongan,
        'totalPages' => round(Lowongan::count() / $itemsPerPage)
    ]);
}
```

Vue component :

```
...
data() {
    return {
        list_lowongan: [],
        currentPage: 1,
        itemsPerPage: 3,
        totalPages: 1
    };
},
async mounted() {
    await this.getData()
},
methods: {
    async getData() {
        try {
            let res = await axios.get('lowongan/list', {
                params: {
                    currentPage: this.currentPage,
                    itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage,
                }
            })
            this.totalPages = res.data.totalPages
            this.list_lowongan = res.data.items
        }catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    },
    async prevPage() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1) {
            this.currentPage--;
            await this.getData()
        }
    },
    async nextPage() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.totalPages) {
            this.currentPage++;
            await this.getData()
        }
    }
},
 ...
```

Laravel has [pagination](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html) support...